# "Как и ожидалось" - запятая или двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

Например:
Как и ожидалось(?) ни денег, ни вещей - ничего не было.

Заранее благодарю за ответ!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычно  в таких предложениях ставится запятая:  ***Как и ожидалось, ни денег, ни вещей – ничего не было.***

Это вводное предложение с союзом КАК. Ничего  –  обобщающее слово после однородного ряда, перед ним ставится тире.

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=127#pp127

§ 92. Вводные предложения имеют значения, близкие к значениям вводных слов и сочетаний слов. Они выделяются запятыми либо, значительно реже, — знаком тире. Некрасивого, доброго человека, каким он себя считал, можно, полагал он, любить как приятеля (Л. Т.); Как выражаются моряки, ветер крепчал (Ч.); У нее, как говорят писатели, вырвался вздох облегчения (Бел.); Сидят здесь под страхом смерти и — что еще хуже — под проливным дождем (Каз.).

Пример: ***Как и ожидалось, меня попросили вон из беленых стен.*** [Владимир Маканин. (1996-1997)]